# how to capture packets in a Windows application that must be installed as non-admin?

Tags: .net, network-programming, winsock, windows, packet-sniffers

Is it possible to write a Windows app that can capture packets on the PC such that this application can be installed/run as non-admin?  If yes, what would be the approach, e.g. which language, which API/Library to use etc (e.g. would it be with the Windows Sockets 2 (Winsock) library?)

I've looked at Network Monitor API's however the issue here is that NM needs to be installed, and this requires "admin" access (to get the driver in place).

Note what I'm after is to capture/monitor packets to sum frame sizes for all packets of a particular type [e.g. HTTP] going out to a specific set of IPs.

thanks

Comment: You would hope that an application without administrative rights could not gain access to the traffic other applications send. A serious security violation otherwise.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to ascertain - whether it's a hard constraint within Windows or not - or perhaps the answer may be different between XP, Vista, Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this helps, but you can run any application with different privileges than that of the currently logged in user. See "Run as" tools.

Comment: thanks - but main issue here is for users with non-admin access, and I know things like Network Monitor API does require admin access for the install of the drivers that get used to allow the packet capture